# Does Podman support private registry

Tags: podman

My understanding is that when Podman pulls an image, it caches it to a users home directory - eg)  ~/.local/share/containers. Docker provides a mechanism for a private image registry that enables sharing amongst a project team. I cannot find any reference to a similar concept with Podman. How does Podman manage private images that need sharing in a team?

I'm struggling to find any references to Podman private registry. 0 search results on StackOverflow for this topic.

Comment: There is no technical distinction between "private" and "public" registries. **private** is not a registry/client feature, it is environment attribute. If the remote side can speak Registry API, it is a registry and it is supported. If it is accessible, `podman` will talk to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does! If you are using Podman with Ubuntu, you will have to create the appropriate registry configuration files in `/etc/containers` to gain access to public and private registries.

There are two files in charge for the configuration `/etc/containers/registries.conf` and `/etc/containers/policy.json`.

You can found an example and more information here -> https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-podman-on-ubuntu/

The technology beneath, the registry management, is based on project Skopeo -> https://github.com/containers/skopeo